# CakePHP 3 - How to automatically show form errors for multiple new entities?

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to leverage any automatic handling of validation and displaying errors for a form using multiple entities.

The user can dynamically create multiple new entities via the form UI. The data is marshalled through `newEntities()`:

```
$this->MyModel->newEntities($data);
```

The first part of the problem I have is that in order to check if validation failed on any of the entities, I have to do it manually by checking every entity:

```
$errors = false;
foreach ($entities as $entity) {
    if ($entity->errors()) {
        $errors = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!$errors) {
    // Save...
```

Does Cake provide anything out of the box which allows you to check if `newEntities()` failed validation on any of its entities? If not, then never mind...

The main problem is how I get the errors from the individual entities to then show inline in my form next to the relevant inputs.

```
<?= $this->Form->create(); ?>
```

What can I pass to `create()` to link it to the entities? At the moment there doesn't seem to be any way for it to know what happens once the form is submitted, and therefore doesn't show errors.

My form inputs are created using the standard array notation, where `$i` comes from the loop building the form inputs from all the entities.

```
$this->Form->hidden("MyModel.$i.field");
```

Comment: There is no "master array" by default in CakePHP any way. You must do something wrong in your code because the marshaller will trigger validation on creating of new entities. Go through the marshaller code if you want to see how and where. If everything is right Cake will show the errors automatically in your form. See the many() and one() method in the marshaller. http://api.cakephp.org/3.3/source-class-Cake.ORM.Marshaller.html and you'll see it validates there. Calling errors() on the entity is not required to trigger validation. Hydration of entities is required but enabled by default.

Comment: @burzum See updated question. I know how the marshalling works, that is not really the issue. It's more how can I check in the controller that any of the entities are invalid, and how can I link the form to the multiple entities so it shows inline errors in the view?

Comment: Well, the question didn't sound like you do. Why do you need to check that in the controller? If save() returned false it is likely that validation or application rules failed. If your form field notation is correct and the entities passed back to the form(s) they should show automatically up. It would help to show the form and the data structure, a complete example.

Comment: @burzum *"...the entities passed back to the form"* Right, but how do I do that? With a single entity it can be passed to `FormHelper::create()` but how to do that for an array of entities so it shows the errors via `FormHelper`? That is the part I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply pass the array of entities to your form

```
$this->Form->create($entities);
```

also you don't have to specify the model name in the input name. Simply

```
$this->Form->hidden("$i.field");
```

and not

```
$this->Form->hidden("MyModel.$i.field");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use newEntity and add those to an array. Loop over that array accessing errors().

```
$array = [];
$array[] = $TableRegistry->newEntity([
    'hi' => 'hey'
]);

foreach($array as $r){
    var_dump($r->errors());
}
```

Hopefully that works with your use-case. I've never used newEntities, but you may be able to iterate over that as well?

Comment: The marshaller of the framework is exactly doing this internally. Go through the code path and you'll see it. http://api.cakephp.org/3.3/source-class-Cake.ORM.Marshaller.html#309-340